# Custom UITableviewCell transparent background error Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having problems setting `contentView.backgroundColor` of custom `TableViewCell` to `.clean`. If I set it to any color it works, but when I select `.clean`it keeps showing a withe background. 
I tried assigning the cell's `contentView` to its own outlet but nothing changed.

As always many thanks.

This is the code for the custom Cell :

```
class ProductCategoryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

//    @IBOutlet weak var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bg: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!

    var category: String!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        configureUi()
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        // Set your default background color, title color etc
        configureUi()
    }

    func configureUi() {
        let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 5
        bg.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        bg.layer.borderWidth = 1
        bg.clipsToBounds = true

        if Theme.selectedTheme == 1 {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
//                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red //Theme.backgroundColor

                contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                bg.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColor
                bg.layer.borderColor = Theme.accentColor?.cgColor

                categoryLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColor
                categoryLabel.textColor = Theme.textFieldTextColor
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
//                view.backgroundColor = Theme.backgroundColorRgb

                bg.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColorRgb
                bg.layer.borderColor = Theme.accentColorRgb.cgColor

                categoryLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColorRgb
                categoryLabel.textColor = Theme.textFieldTextColorRgb
            }
        } else if Theme.selectedTheme == 2 {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
//                view.backgroundColor = Theme.backgroundColor2

                bg.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColor2
                bg.layer.borderColor = Theme.accentColor2?.cgColor

                categoryLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColor2
                categoryLabel.textColor = Theme.textFieldTextColor2
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
//                view.backgroundColor = Theme.backgroundColorRgb2

                bg.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColorRgb2
                bg.layer.borderColor = Theme.accentColorRgb2.cgColor

                categoryLabel.backgroundColor = Theme.textFieldBackgroundColorRgb2
                categoryLabel.textColor = Theme.textFieldTextColorRgb2
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Three]

Comment: Check "Debug View Hierarchy" for your views. Maybe bg is not clear? or the label is as big as the cell and that background not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
self.isOpaque = false
```

Repeat it for contentView & bg

Comment: Thanks again, You're always fixing me something hahah

Answer (score 0):

It is working but you are seeing the background color of the parent view, in this case your custom cell background color.

In order to make them all clear you need to set it for the `bg` and `contentView` and `UITableViewCell` and `UITableView` itself so try to set it for all of them:

```
item.backgroundColor = .clear
item.isOpaque = false
```

Replace `item` with the UI items I mentioned above

Comment: The thing that I wasn't realising is that I wasn't doing it on the cell itself as I though I was by setting `contentView`to `.clear`, I only accepted the other answer because of the `self` that made me see it. Thank you very much for putting time into answering.